# Handling an arbitrarily long request in node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, timeout

I have an endpoint that will analyze all of the projects submitted to my webpage between two dates and then download a CSV file with the results. Right now I have an express endpoint that will allow the user to select the dates and then submit to the server which then needs to do some work and will eventually trigger the download of a csv file using the csv module.

This works if the user selects a reasonable narrow range of dates but as the range grows the process may take longer then the nginx timeout time. I could simply increase the timeout time but at some point this will breakdown. How could I re-architect this to not get caught up in a possible timeout?

Answer (score 1):

If you're enforcing a request timeout, then your best bet is probably to have some sort of "ticket" system where the server responds right away with some sort of token ("ticket") that can be used later on to check on the submitted job's status.

From there you could perhaps generate a link that returns the current status (and optionally an additional download link) or if you want to get fancy, you could use something like `socket.io` to allow the client to be automatically notified as soon as the job completes (and presented with a download link).